# Calculating multiple IRRs from a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, irr

I have a Panadas dataframe which encompasses 4 columns (company, price today, cash flow y1, cash flow y2, cash flow y3 (i.e. a terminal value)):

| Code | Price | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GOOGL-US | -2380 | 0 | 0 | 4074.94 |
| AMZN-US | -3265 | 0 | 0 | 5765.09 |
| FB-US | -327 | 0 | 0 | 513.819 |

etc for ~100 tickers

Is there a way to do a simple IRR calc using the data from the columns price, 0, 1, 2 as at annual periods `(i.e. t0, t1, t2, t3)`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have concrete solution but could give you some hint and direction to look for.  There had been a Numpy function [`Numpy.irr()`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.irr.html) supporting IRR calculation in Numpy / Pandas.  However, it had been deprecated since Numpy version 1.18 and moved to separate module at [NumPy Financial](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-financial/) where you can still install it e.g. by:

```
pip install numpy-financial
```

Then use it as, e.g.

```
import numpy_financial as npf

npf.irr([-250000, 100000, 150000, 200000, 250000, 300000])
0.5672303344358536
```

You can refer to this article [Calculating IRR in Python](https://www.codingfinance.com/post/2018-03-20-irr-py/) for some usage examples.

Comment: Yh. The issue I'm having is scaling that framework to calculate it for every ticker in the dataframe